# How to use select sub Query in insert statement?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to insert some values into a database, using insert statement. I have to use select statement as well to get from another table the key that corresponds to the option selected.

I tried several queries but none of them worked.

```
    string query3 = "insert into students (FirstName, LastName, FatherName, 
Email, DateBirth, DateReg, Adress, Gender, Specialization, Country, 
Province, City) values ('" 
    + this.txt_fname.Text + "','" + this.txt_lname.Text + "','" 
    + this.txt_fathername.Text + "','" + this.txt_email.Text + "','" 
    + this.date_birth.Text + "', '" + this.date_reg.Text + "','" 
    + this.txt_adress.Text + "','" + this.Gender 
    + "', (select specialization_id from specialization where SpecializationName = '" + this.specialization.Text 
    + "'),
    (select country_id from country where CountryName ='" + this.comboBox2.Text 
    + "'),(select province_id from province where ProvinceName ='" 
              + this.comboBox4.Text 
    + "'),(select city_id from city where CityName ='"+ this.comboBox3.Text + "');";
```

I expect the output "saved" but I get {"Incorrect syntax near ';'."}

When I use:

```
'" + ("SELECT specialization_id from specialization where SpecializationName =" + this.specialization.Text)+ "'
```

instead of (wrote above):

```
(select specialization_id from specialization where SpecializationName = '" + this.specialization.Text + "')
```

I get:

> {"Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'SELECT specialization_id from specialization where SpecializationName =Informatica Economica' to data type int."}

Comment: Don't use string concatenation to create SQL statements. That's how SQL injection attacks *and* conversion errors occur. Use a proper parameterized query. Quoting and sanitization can cover up some problems but not all. It's better to *not* have that problem to begin with

Comment: [SqlCommand.Parameters Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.8) - Write your code properly and parametrise, and the issue does not exist.

Comment: You should check the contents of the `query3` variable, try them in SSMS and post them here properly formatted. It's impossible to find out what that query does otherwise. Using parameters instead of concatenation would result in a far cleaner query too

Comment: AiR do **not** use the answer you have accepted as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My usual caveat, I'm not a C# programmer, I barely know it, but the documenation I linked before was more than enough for me to write this properly:

```
string commandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.student (FirstName, LastName, FatherName, Email, DateBirth,DateReg, Adress, Gender, Specialization, Country, Province,City) " +
                     "SELECT @FirstName,@LastName, @Fathername, @Email, @DateBirth, @DateReg, @Address, @Gender, s.specialization_id, c.country_id, p.province_id, cy.city_id " +
                     "FROM (SELECT specialization_id FROM dbo.specialization WHERE SpecializationName = @Specialization) s " +
                     "CROSS APPLY (select country_id from country where CountryName = @Country) c " +
                     "CROSS APPLY (select province_id from province where ProvinceName = @Province) p " +
                     "CROSS APPLY (select city_id from city where CityName = @City) cy;";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
    command.Parameters.Add(@FirstName, SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = this.txt_fname.Text;
    command.Parameters.Add(@LastName, SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = this.txt_lname.Text;
    command.Parameters.Add(@Fathername, SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = this.txt_fathername.Text;
    command.Parameters.Add(@Email, SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = this.txt_email.Text;
    command.Parameters.Add(@DateBirth, SqlDbType.Date).Value = this.date_birth.Text; //Shouldn't this be a date picker object?
    command.Parameters.Add(@DateReg, SqlDbType.Date).Value = this.date_reg.Text; //Shouldn't this be a date picker object?
    command.Parameters.Add(@Address, SqlDbType.VarChar,200).Value = this.txt_adress.Text; //It's spelt Address (2 d's)
    command.Parameters.Add(@Gender, SqlDbType.VarChar,10).Value = this.Gender; //Why did this not have the Text property?
    command.Parameters.Add(@Specialization, SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = this.specialization.Text;
    command.Parameters.Add(@CountryName, SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = this.comboBox2.Text; //You should name this combo box
    command.Parameters.Add(@Province, SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = this.comboBox4.Text; //You should name this combo box
    command.Parameters.Add(@City, SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = this.comboBox3.Text;//You should name this combo box
}
```

Comment: @Larnu, perfect answer. This is how it should be done.